# Spinner OnItemSelectedListener Not Working

Tags: java, android, spinner

I am in the middle of creating an android app ...I have two Spinner drop down lists. it seems that I cannot get the OnItemSelectedListener to work properly. I get no errors when an item is selected , it just returns null..I spent all day trying to figure out what I did wrong..with no luck.

below is the relevent code.please let me know if you need any more code

```
  //grab the user defined make and model for the listing search
    spin_make = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinr_make);
    spin_model = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinr_model);

    //load the drop downs
    ArrayAdapter<String> makeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, make_list);
    spin_make.setAdapter(makeAdapter);    

    //set the item selected listener for the make drop down
    spin_make.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            model_list.clear();
            new LoadModelListsTask().execute();
            ArrayAdapter<String> modelAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, model_list);
            spin_model.setAdapter(modelAdapter);
            _make = make_list.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: can you put down the other spinner onItemSelected and your code for loading the make_list arrayList

Comment: I stepped threw the code line by line..the make_list has 109 items in it which is expected....the on item selected isnt even firing..not sure why?

Comment: I think you have a synchronization problem.

Comment: The problem occur when you set spinner adaper with **model_list** , but your asyntask **LoadModelListsTask** not finish. Are you check this case ?

Comment: ok..I commented out all the code in the onSelected method.and added a Toast..but when I click a item in the dropdown, the toast is never shown!